# Java CompletableFuture.allOf() doesn't find any array elements

Tags: java, future

A very simple code snippet as below:

```
String[] list = {"a", "b", "c"};
List<CompletableFuture<String>> completableFutureList = new ArrayList<>();
for (String s : list) {
    completableFutureList.add(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> s)
            .thenApply(String::toUpperCase));
}
CompletableFuture<String>[] a = completableFutureList
        .toArray(new CompletableFuture[completableFutureList.size()]);
System.out.println(a.length);
CompletableFuture.allOf(a).whenComplete((r, e) -> {
    if (null != r) {
        System.out.println(r);
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
});
```

I expect the program should print "A B C". But actually nothing is printed. Why and how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Citing the Javadoc of the `CompletableFuture.allOf()` method (emphasis mine):

> Returns a new `CompletableFuture` that is completed when all of
>        the given `CompletableFutures` complete.  If any of the given
>        `CompletableFutures` complete exceptionally, then the returned
>        `CompletableFuture` also does so, with a `CompletionException`
>        holding this exception as its cause.  **Otherwise, the results,
>        if any, of the given `CompletableFutures` are not reflected in
>        the returned `CompletableFuture`, but may be obtained by
>        inspecting them individually.** If no `CompletableFutures` are
>        provided, returns a `CompletableFuture` completed with the value
>        {@code null}.

So I think that you need to query them manually (by using `a[0].get()` for example) in the `whenComplete()` callback. Something like this:

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(a).whenComplete((r, e) -> {
    for (CompletableFuture<String> future : a) {
        try {
           System.out.println(future.get());
        }
        catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e1) {
           e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```